# Increment returned integer in loop

Tags: php, function, loops, foreach, increment

How can I get the returned $i from the function getLast() and increment it in my foreach?

```
protected function getLast($array = [])
{
    foreach($array as $file)
    {
        $getLast[] = substr($file, -5, 1);
    }

    $i = (int)$getLast[0];

    return $i;
}

protected function foo()
{
    $this->getLast($gl);
    foreach($array as $img)
    {
        # ...
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: by storing the return value in the variable `$i`? i.e. `$i=$this->getLast($gl);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use reference to get the value of variable $i

Code:

```
protected function getLast($array = [], &$i)
{
    foreach($array as $file)
    {
        $getLast[] = substr($file, -5, 1);
    }

    $i = (int)$getLast[0];
}

protected function foo()
{
    $i = 0;
    $this->getLast($gl, $i);
    foreach($array as $img)
    {
        # ...
        $i++;
    }
}
```

in your situation `$i = $this->getLast($gl);`

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the result of the function to a new variable.

```
protected function foo()
{
    $i = $this->getLast($gl);
    foreach($array as $img)
    {
        # ...
        $i++;
    }
}
```

But this will not be the same `$i`, it'll be another variable. I suppose you need a value, not a reference to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function returns a value - this is your i. So you only need to assing its return value in function occurence.

```
$i = $this->getLast($gl);
```